# NoSuchMethodError: No static method getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; in class Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger

Tags: java, android

I am using Reflection concept in my project to load classes and displaying the corresponding details of a particular class. But some of java jdk classes are not present in android sdk for which I added rt.jar as an external library.

Now some of the classes were able to load successfully which are not there is android sdk like ("javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder") but some are causing the application to crash whenever I try to load them like ("javax.swing.AbstractButton") with an error for getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger.

I am using the very basic code to load classes as

```
String className = editText().getText().toString();

Class c = Class.forName(className);
```

How this problem can be solved so that I can able to load all classes present inside rt.jar which I added externally.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of java sdk  classes is not present in android. Most certainly javax.swing.* classes. Consult sdk documentation for complete reference.    Only solution is to remember that android is not quite java  and use classes available to android platform.   And user interface in android is not done with swing - so why do you need those classes in  first line?

Comment: I am aware that all java jdk classes are not present in android sdk but my target is to load all java jdk classes to get their related information and that's why I added rt.jar as an external library and also I don't need swing classes to build any UI, but what if I want to know the constructors, methods or fields of a class which are inside the swing package...

Comment: You are aware that you can not load class you do not have any  bytecode for?    Bytecode for those classes is not present in androird JDK ( well ADK ) -   however, you can include all the jar files you like  into your APK and then you will be able to load those classes (of course you need transient closure of all referenced classes).  So adding rt.jar is not enough and desired class you can not load sits is come other jar file provided with standard jdk

Comment: so what might me the solution...should I use classes which are common in both android sdk and java jdk or if I add external rt.jar how to get rid of this error (NoSuchMethodError: No static method getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; in class Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger
). Because I am able to load "javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder" and "javax.swing.AbstractAction" and not "javax.swing.AbstractButton" while the mentioned classes are in javax.swing package only

Comment: what about loading only classes present in your environment?  an displaying that there is no such class if there is no such class

Comment: I would be glad to know how to fix the error for NoSuchMethodError else I have no other option to separate classes which are common in both java jdk and android sdk as I want to provide flexibility to the end user because then there is no reason left to build the app if I am not able to give the full functionality...thank you anyways!

Comment: Just add jar containint missing java classes ( PLatform logger ) to your APK.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue? I'm facing the exactly same issue here.